# Is it good to use SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN?

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I am reading the SDL_CreateTexture function I am getting really confused on what parameter to chose for the "Uint32 format" argument.  There are a lot of enumerated values and I don't know which one to chose and why.  I don't know why SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN seems like a good idea. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your question does not provide enough context to really tell you what to do here.

- What do you want to achieve?
- What have you already tried?
- Does it throw errors?

I'll try to give you some general hints:
The texture is just a big array, with all pixels saved one after another, line after line, read from left to right and top to bottom (at least usually).
This array has the length: 
`length_in_bytes = w * h * nBytesOfPixel;`
So to properly allocate memory for the texture, and correctly interpret the bytes as pixel colors, the number of bytes (or bits in this case) in a pixel are needed. 
To inform `SDL_CreateTexture` about this, you have to provide one of these Pixelformat values. If in doubt, use `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888` which should cover all your bases for a while and translates easily from anywhere else. As the name indicates, it saves every pixel as 4 bytes, 1 byte for each color, in the order: **R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue, **A**lpha. Alpha is used for transparency.

If you compare this to some of the other candidates, you can probably see what their properties are.

- `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGR888` for instance has the **B** and **R** channels swapped and no alpha channel.

Comment: While this could be good schematic description, `length_in_bytes = w * h * nBytesOfPixel` is wrong; it is `pitch * h`. Doesn't matter for RGBA8888, but could be very different thing for e.g. 3 byte per pixel formats.

Comment: @keltar: Isn't it the responsibility of the functions the OP is asking about to translate this? Since the constants are hardware dependent? Can there be a case where `w * nBytesOfPixel == pitch` does not hold? Some per-line-padding or something?

Comment: Yes, SDL uses 4-byte alignment for lines. If bpp is 4, it wouldn't matter, as each pixel hits alignment rule. If bpp is 3 (e.g no alpha channel and no packing to uint32) - well, you can easily have 1-to-3 bytes padding at the end of each line.